# Breaking variable passed through command line in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a line in my playbook which is as follows

```
ftp://user:password@mysite/pub/ec/component/12.05/{{ version }}/product-{{ version }}-Linux2.6_64-release.tar
```

When i am running the playbook, i am getting the value of version from command line using --extra-vars as follows

```
ansible-playbook  -l dbservers test.yml -vvvv --extra-vars "version=12.06.010"
```

Now what i want is when the user enters the value say 12.06.010 the ftp path will be created automatically as

```
ftp://user:password@mysite/pub/ec/component/12.06/12.06.010/product-12.06.010-Linux2.6_64-release.tar
```

That is the user entry will be broken into two parts --> The first two parts will form the major version and the entire version will be the product version

IS there any way this can be achieved.?

Comment: are you trying to get get the `12.06` part from the `version` variable? Can you clarify on exactly you want to be dynamically generated that will depend on your variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

```
ftp://user:password@mysite/pub/ec/component/{{ version[:-4] }}/{{ version }}/product-{{ version }}-Linux2.6_64-release.tar
```

This will only work if you are absolutely sure that the last part of the version will always consist of 3 characters(and the dot).
What I'm doing there is I'm using "slicing" to slice the string to everything but the last 4 characters.

Another way to go will be:

```
ftp://user:password@mysite/pub/ec/component/{{ version.split('.')[0] }}.{{ version.split('.')[1] }}/{{ version }}/product-{{ version }}-Linux2.6_64-release.tar
```

In this scenario you have to write a bit more, however, you don't have to worry about the length of the last part of the version. This method will work as long as you keep the same format of versioning(with 2 dots).

The way it works is that `variable` is split into an array(in this case of 3 elements) and it picks the first and the second element(and puts a dot in between them).